# Service script calls another script with variables

Tags: shell-script, rhel, variable-substitution

I have a simple service script `tomcat7` in /etc/init.d/ to start and stop my app server (tomcat) under the tomcat user. On RHEL6.

```
#!/bin/bash
# description: Tomcat Start Stop
# processname: tomcat
# chkconfig: 234 20 80

CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/www/tomcat-7.0.54

case $1 in
start)
/bin/su tomcat $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
;;
stop)
/bin/su tomcat $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh 30
;;
esac
exit 0
```

Which works fine. Both `startup.sh` and `shutdown.sh` call a script called `catalina.sh`. These are pre-made scripts that come with the app server.

I can use `catalina.sh` directly like:
`./catalina.sh stop 30 -force`

Which lets me specify a wait time of 30 seconds and then does a kill -9 if the process hasn't ended. But I can't get the variables to work in the `tomcat7` service script. If I change it to:

```
stop)
/bin/su tomcat $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh stop 30 -force
```

I get an error:

```
[root@543917-web1 bin]# service tomcat7 stop
/bin/su: invalid option -- 'o'
```

Can I pass the three arguments without altering the catalina.sh script?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [su](http://linux.die.net/man/1/su) with `-c`:

```
/bin/su tomcat -c "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh stop 30 -force"
```

From `su` man page:

```
-c, --command=COMMAND
    pass a single COMMAND to the shell with -c
```